# Add buttons to SharePoint model dialog via javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, modal-dialog

I am trying to add some buttons to SharePoint model dialog through Javascript but nothing seems to work. Following is my code.

```
     var htmlElement = document.createElement('p');
     var btnCancel = document.createElement("Button");
     btnCancel.className = 'Test';
     var txtCancel = document.createTextNode("Cancel");
     btnCancel.appendChild(txtCancel);
     htmlElement.appendChild(btnCancel);
     btnCancel.addEventListener("click", testFunction );
```

Is it possible to add elements dynamically to SharePoint model dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are creating an element, but you haven't appended it to anything in the DOM in order for it to show. You've appended your button to the paragraph that you created, but you never appended your paragraph (htmlElement) to anything that exists in the DOM.